# How to set the center alignment for an image in a column and have the text appear below it?

Tags: html, jquery, css, alignment

How to set the center alignment for an image in a column and have the text appear below it?

```css
    div.col_text {
    columns: 2;
    }
    
    div img {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: black;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col_text">
<img/>
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give it: `margin: 0 auto`, and `display:block`

**display:block** sets it to a block, so the content is forced below it.

**margin: 0 auto** sets the top and bottom margin to 0 and left and right to auto which will center.

```css
div.col_text {
    columns: 2;
    }
    
    div img {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: black;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block
    }
```

```html
<div class="col_text">
<img/>
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 

</div>
```